# Xpath select node text but exclude child node text

Tags: string, xpath, tags

I have the following XML:

```
<topic class="Top">
    <title>
        Interesting Article
    </title>
    <subtitle>
        Science & Industry
        <insertedText action="start"/>
            Inside & Out
        <insertedText action="end"/>
        A Profile
    </subtitle>
</topic>
```

And I would like to use xpath to extract the text of the subtitle, except for the string between the two `<insertedText>` nodes, giving the text "Science & Industry A Profile".

Here is my latest attempt but to be honest I'm stumped and realise that this does not exclude the text between the two tags! Any help would be appreciated:

`/topic[@class='Top']/*[local-name()='subtitle'][not(descendant::insertedText)]/text()`

The number of `<insertedText>` tags is also variable, so there may be none or multiple sets on `<insertedText>` tags which should be ignored.

A further example of the type XML that might be encountered is below:

```
<topic class="Top">
    <title>
        Interesting Article
    </title>
    <subtitle>
        Science & Industry
        <insertedText action="start"/>
            Inside & Out
        <insertedText action="end"/>
        A Profile
        <insertedText action="start"/>
            An Insiders View
        <insertedText action="end"/>
        The Full Story
    </subtitle>
</topic>
```

**Answer**

The full answer, based on that provided by @lambo477, is as follows:

```
./topic[@class='top']/*[local-name()='subtitle']/text()[1]|/topic[@class='top']/*[local-name()='subtitle']/*[local-name()='insertedText'][@action='end']/following-sibling::node()[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following XPath:

```
//subtitle/text()[1]|//insertedText[@action="end"]/following-sibling::node()[1]
```

Comment: Thanks @lambo477, however I've edited my OP to clarify, the number of <insertedText> nodes is also variable.

Comment: I think my solution should work either way? It will select the text before and after the children nodes

Comment: Ah yes @lambo477, I see that now. Although there may be circumstances where the number of <insertedText> tags may be more than one or none! I've expanded my OP again for clarity, thanks again.

Comment: What would the desired output be for example 2?

Comment: My solution also works for cases where there are 0, 1 or >1 children elements, so I can't see the issue!

Comment: The desired output @lambo477 for the 2nd XML example would be "Science & Industry A Profile The Full Story", so unfortunately I don't think your solution would work in that case or am I completely mistaken?

Comment: We got there in the end?